# How can I use the Developer Tools Console to access a variable declared inside a module?

Tags: javascript

[image: The scripts and the console.log]

**index.js**

```
import { Player } from "./Players.js"
const player1 = new Player;
player1.getCharacter()
```

Here I import *class Player*, into my main javaScript file, defined as `export class Player {}` from Players.js

Then I initialize a player1 object and assign to it an instance of the Player class.

Then I call a method from player1 which exist within the Player class.

MY PROBLEM is ... Within the browser, the console tells me player1 is not defined. Whereas the method works as I can player1.getCharacter(). However the function is being called from Players.js.

HOW TO make the browser aware of the new instance ?!

I've tried to instantiate a new object but it doesn't seem to work as chrome's browser tells me it is undefined when I try to call it.

console.log(player1)
// player1 is undefined

update:

- I CAN NOT access player's properties
- The instantiation is made within the global scope (Not nested)

Comment: You're using `import`, so you have a module. That means that variables declared in your module are **not** global variables (`window` properties). If you don't get an error from the last line (the call to `.getCharacter()`), then you know the variable is being defined.

Comment: @DanielA.White the `()` is optional in a constructor call (with no parameters, obviously).

Comment: Daniel A. White - That's true I forgot the parenthesis however if I remember it's optional in javaScript but not best practice. Tried with the parenthesis and I get the same error. 

player1 is undefined. 

Thank you.

Comment: Pointy - Yes I have a *<script type='module' src='index.js'>* Here I declare the *const new Player* within the index.js which should make it accessible from the console ? I get no error but only when I try to call the *player1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules have their own scope. `const`s declared inside them are scoped to the module (just as `const`s declared inside a function are scoped to the function).

This presents you with two problems:

1. The `const` *no longer exists* (because it will have been cleaned up when the module finishes executing)
2. The Console only has access to the *current* scope which, at the time you are trying to access `player1` is only the global scope.

There are two ways to deal with this.

## Globals

The **awful** way is to make `player1` a global. Then it will live beyond the life of the module.

```
 window.player1 = player1;
```

This requires that you edit the source code and pollute the global scope (throwing away one of the great benefits of modules).

## Debugging tools

[Create a **breakpoint**](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/debugger/how_to/set_a_breakpoint/index.html) at a point where player1 exists (e.g. on the statement immediately after its creation in the source code).

You could do this with an explicit `debugger;` statement or by clicking next to the line in the debugger in your browser's developer tools.

Then, with the developer tools open, refresh the page to make the module be executed again.

When the debugger pauses at the breakpoint, the Console will have access to the scope of the module.

Not that you are likely to need it just to inspect `player1` since it will be displayed by the debugger anyway:

[image: Screenshot of the Firefox debugger]

Comment: That's right. The constant is accessible with a break point, after its declaration, then it gets destroyed.

Thanks for the ugly method *window.player1 = player1*.

Would there be a more elegant way ? 

Thank you !